# change mysql table character set

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that data was inserted in it some time ago.  data included by php and  character set in it was utf-8 .

```
mysql_query("set names utf8");
```

now ,I need this table in another project which all data will show on php mysql default character set.

problem : my data is persian, when I set charachter set utf-8, every things is ok, but without character set data convert to the "?????" what should I do?!

I want to import all data form old table to new table on new character set !!

Comment: Check this: http://www.devcha.com/2008/03/convert-existing-mysql-database-from.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//charset-conversion.html

Comment: Use UTF-8. If the data is unicode, use unicode. There is no reason for the "other project" to leave the charset decision to MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
///
$SERVER = "http://localhost:8084";
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die("Not Connected");
$sldb = mysql_select_db('vifarbydata',$db);

mysql_query("set names utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `region`  ";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($h=(mysql_fetch_array($res)))
{
    $row[] = $h;
}
mysql_close($db);
/// set another character set
$SERVER = "http://localhost:8084";
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die("Not Connected");
$sldb = mysql_select_db('vifarbydata',$db);
foreach ($row as $item)
{
    echo $sql = "insert into  `region2` (id,name,myId) values (".$item['id'].",'".$item['name']."','".$item['myId']."')  ";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help you

```
<?php

   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
and then in the connection

<?php
 $dbLink = mysql_connect($argHost, $argUsername, $argPassword);
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink);
    mb_language('uni'); 
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mysql_select_db($argDB, $dbLink);
    mysql_query("set names 'utf8'",$dbLink);
?>
```

Comment: I dont want to set character set utf-8 , I want to convert my old table to new one that I havent to change my character set just for this table!!is it possible?!!

Answer (score 0):

@afsane, using mysqldump, you can dump the data from old_table and then import it into the new_table which has the new character encoding.

```
mysqldump -u user -p --no-create-info schema old_table > old_table.dump
mysql -u user -p schema new_table < old_table.dump
```

This will be much faster than doing a conversion via PHP.